# How to set default personality for a kernel?

Tags: linux, search, 64bit

I'm trying to replace a 32-bit kernel with a 64-bit one on a 32-bit system, so that I had the complete support for 64 bits for the apps which need it (provided they have the necessary libraries or are statically linked), but retaining 32-bit userspace for all others. The problem is that many of the 32-bit userspace apps expect `uname -m` to report `i686`, so I need to do `setarch i386` before running anything, prefereably even before `init`.

I guess I could do something like passing `init=/sbin/myinit` to the kernel, where `myinit` has something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec setarch i386 /sbin/init
```

But I'd instead like to have a way to encode default personality into the kernel itself. Is there any existing kernel option to do this?

Comment: Does your computer support a 64 bit system in the first place?

Comment: To the previous comment's point, do you have a 32 or 64 bit processor? Run the following `lscpu | grep op-mode` and post the result. You can readily run a 32 bit kernel and add the 64 bit arch to a system with a 64 bit processor, but the opposite is a very different story. Running 64 bit code on a 32 bit processor can be done, but it typically requires emulation (very slow) or virtualization (limited CPU support).

Comment: @JuliePelletier yes of course, otherwise I wouldn't bother with a 64-bit kernel. I've already tried a LiveUSB with a 64-bit system, but as my machine doesn't have too much RAM, it appeared to not be nice WRT memory usage, so I'd rather have 32-bit userspace with a 64-bit kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such kernel option as far as I can tell. You can take a look yourself through the kernel source if you want; relevant things to search for are `set_personality` and `current->personality`. The flag you want is `PER_LINUX32`.

Short of patching the kernel, your solution of overriding init is probably the simplest one. This isn't really out of the ordinary; it's quite similar to using an initramfs. If you're already using an initramfs, you could put your `setarch` in there.